# Expo/React Native error - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'string.toLowerCase')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

So I'm making an React Native app, I have server and db set up on heroku.
Using expo to view it on the phone and in web browser on my pc.

On web, everything works right.

On phone, I get the error from the screenshot. I guess there's a problem with data not coming on time or maybe there's a different way of writing things?

Is there a way to get full app on phone without using android studio?

[image]

Here's the code related to error:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder='Search...'
    onChange={(e) => { this.handleInput(e.target.value) }}
></TextInput>


handleInput = (value) => {
  if (value !== this.state.insertionIngredient) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, insertionIngredient: value });
  };
};

handleFindButton = () => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: true });

  const id = searchString(this.state.insertionLanguage, this.state.data, 
                          this.state.insertionIngredient);
  const result = getById(this.state.queryLanguage, this.state.data, id);

  if (id === 'No such word in the database.' || result === 'No such word in the database.') {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, queryIngredient: 'No such word in the database.' });
  } else {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, queryIngredient: result });
  };
};

const searchString = (language, state, string) => {
  let array;
  if (language === 'english') {
      array = state.english;
  } else if (language === 'spanish') {
      array = state.spanish;
  } else if (language === 'german') {
      array = state.german;
  } else if (language === 'serbian') {
      array = state.serbian;
  };

  string = string.toLowerCase();
  let filter = escapeRegExp(string);
  let regex = new RegExp("^" + filter, "i");

  const word = array.filter(val => {
      return val.word.match(regex)
  });

  if (word.length > 0) {
      return word[0].id;
  } else {
      return 'No such word in the database';
  }};
```

[image: How app looks]

Comment: With the limited code and snapshots available, I can only suspect if the error is related to state `insertionIngredient`, having different values. I would suggest inserting a couple of log statements to track the value of `insertionIngredient` within all the function bodies.

Also, instead of passing the args to `searchString(this.state.insertionLanguage, this.state.data, this.state.insertionIngredient)`.. I would suggest, call `searchString()` with no args and access the language, state, string values from the state.

Comment: I can try to bring the code back to the main component instead of importing it, but I don't think that will resolve the issue.

Comment: No, I meant, keep the code in your component only but maybe change the way you've laid out your logic. Your code blocks, which looks linear doesn't actually execute serially but rather all lines are executed in parallel. My point being, the `state` might have different value for `insertionIngredient` than what we might be expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from reading the error, I believe you're running into situations when `string` is undefined. A simple work around would be to check if `string` exists, then apply toLowerCase to it if does. Example:

`if (string) string = string.toLowerCase();`

`else console.log("string doesn't exist, look into it");`

Comment: I know that's the issue, but string can't be empty because it's generated on input value change with onChange method. It can only be undefined if there is a delay due to expo broadcasting app on my phone.

Comment: For the sake of debugging, can you try using `onChangeText()` method instead of `onChange()`.  In your example:
`<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder='Search...'
    onChangeText={(userInput) => { this.handleInput(userInput) }}
></TextInput>`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I used onChange method instead of onChangeText. So instead of this:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder='Search...'
  onChange={(e) => { this.handleInput(e.target.value) }}
></TextInput>
```

I should have put this:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder='Search...'
  onChangeText={(e) => { this.handleInput(e) }}
></TextInput>
```